# Android Studio Dolphin: Where is the Terminate Application Icon in the new Logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-studio-dolphin

In Android Studio Dolphin, there's a new Logcat for experiments. When I turn it on, I notice the Terminate Application icon is missing as shown in the diagram below.

The Termination Application icon is very useful as shared in [this article](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/shortcut-to-dont-keep-activity-simulation-aa4a961430aa?sk=a540f595f59361ce66b4e3916e50cd0d). It is different from the Stop Icon. I hope the Google team didn't remove it from the new Logcat.

[image]

Comment: More follow up here https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/yisqoc/where_is_the_terminate_application_icon_in_the/